# NDSolve second-order PDE with 4 variables

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I'm trying to numerically solve a second-order partial differential equation in 4 dimensions. The PDE is a Fokker-Planck equation and the variables are the real and imaginary parts of the field of two coupled oscillators. I try to solve this with NDSolve using Dirichlet boundaries, but I get a strange error. I first create a 4-dimensional region in which the solution has to be found.

```
xmin = 0;
xmax = 13;
ymin = -10;
ymax = 10;
dbc = {DirichletCondition[P[x1, y1, x2, y2] == 0.0, True]};
Ω4d = 
 Parallelepiped[{xmin, ymin, xmin, 
   ymin}, {{xmax - xmin, 0, 0, 0}, {0, ymax - ymin, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    xmax - xmin, 0}, {0, 0, 0, ymax - ymin}}]
```

Then I create a very nasty PDE which I call `pde`
$$\left(-0.02 \text{x1}^2 \text{y1}+1. \text{x1}^3+1. \text{x1} \text{y1}^2+1. \text{x1}+0.1 \text{x2}-0.02 \text{y1}^3-0.002 \text{y2}\right) P^{(0,1,0,0)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+\left(-1. \text{x1}^2 \text{y1}-0.02 \text{x1}^3-0.02 \text{x1} \text{y1}^2-0.002 \text{x2}-1. \text{y1}^3-1. \text{y1}-0.1 \text{y2}\right) P^{(1,0,0,0)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+\left(0.1 \text{x1}-0.02 \text{x2}^2 \text{y2}+1. \text{x2}^3+1. \text{x2} \text{y2}^2+1. \text{x2}+0.018 \text{y1}-0.02 \text{y2}^3-0.02 \text{y2}\right) P^{(0,0,0,1)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+\left(0.018 \text{x1}-1. \text{x2}^2 \text{y2}-0.02 \text{x2}^3-0.02 \text{x2} \text{y2}^2-0.02 \text{x2}-0.1 \text{y1}-1. \text{y2}^3-1. \text{y2}\right) P^{(0,0,1,0)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+\left(-0.04 \text{x1}^2-0.04 \text{x2}^2-0.04 \text{y1}^2-0.04 \text{y2}^2-0.04\right) P(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})=0.02 P^{(0,0,0,2)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+0.02 P^{(0,0,2,0)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+0.002 P^{(0,2,0,0)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})+0.002 P^{(2,0,0,0)}(\text{x1},\text{y1},\text{x2},\text{y2})$$
I try to solve this with

```
NDSolve[{pde, dbc}, P, {x1, y1, x2, y2} ∈ Ω4d]
```

But I get the following error message

```
NDSolve::fem3: -- Message text not found -- (Parallelepiped[{0,-10,0,-10},{{13,0,0,0},{0,20,0,0},{0,0,13,0},{0,0,0,20}}])
```

If I solve with

```
NDSolve[{pde, dbc}, P, {x1, xmin, xmax}, {y1, ymin, ymax}, {x2, xmin,xmax}, {y2, ymin, ymax}]
```

I get

```
NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite element method as implemented in Version 12.1 (and 12.2) can solve PDEs in space dimensions, 1, 2 and 3. So a 4D spatial PDE can not be solved with the FEM.

You can use the TensorProductGrid method to solve 4D PDEs but then you will have to use a rectangular domain.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know which method can solve a 4D PDE?

Comment: @Philip, see update.

Comment: All numerical methods such as FD, RBF-FD and RBF-HFD can be used for solving a 4D PDE problem on TensorProductGrid. Especially their variants on non-uniform grids might be better. However the solvers may suffer of curse of dimensionality and thus a careful tuning of some input variables might be needed.